# Div is not correctly rendered on Safari 10.0.1 (like if there is an overflow:hidden somewhere but there isn't)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a sub-menu that shows when user hovers the main menu item. It works fine in all browsers except Safari (i have version 10.0.1).

I've looked deeply into the code but didn't find any solution. It seems like there is some kind of overflow issue somewhere but I'm not able to find where.

This is the expected behaviour on Chrome:
[Working menu on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ4wp.png)

This is the result on Safari:
[Issue on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbAXr.png)

I did some research here on Stackoverflow but didn't find anything useful, mostly because I don't even know what keywords to use.

This is the website: http://stage.federicalotti.com/

Html code:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">

    <nav id="nav">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="main-menu">
                <ul id="menu-menu-principale" class="menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-16">
                        <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/">
                            <span class="menu-text">Homepage</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19">
                        <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/biografia/">
                            <span class="menu-text">Biografia</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-24" class="no-link menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-24">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="menu-text">Repertorio</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26">
                                <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/lista-brani/">
                                    <span class="menu-text">Lista brani</span>
                                    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25">
                                <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/proposte-concertistiche/">
                                    <span class="menu-text">Proposte concertistiche</span>
                                    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-47" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47">
                        <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/concerti/">
                            <span class="menu-text">Concerti</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-48">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="menu-text">Media</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46">
                                <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/fotografie/">
                                    <span class="menu-text">Fotografie</span>
                                    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45">
                                <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/audio-files/">
                                    <span class="menu-text">Audio files</span>
                                    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44">
                                <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/riprese-video/">
                                    <span class="menu-text">Riprese video</span>
                                    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-43">
                                <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/rassegna-stampa/">
                                    <span class="menu-text">Rassegna stampa</span>
                                    <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-42">
                        <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/news/">
                            <span class="menu-text">News</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41">
                        <a href="http://stage.federicalotti.com/contatti/">
                            <span class="menu-text">Contatti</span>
                            <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- .main-menu -->

            <div class="search-bar-mobile">
                <div class="container">
                    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://stage.federicalotti.com/">
                        <label>
                            <span class="screen-reader-text">Cerca:</span>
                            <input type="text" class="search-field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cerca..." name="s" title="Cerca:">
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Cerca">
                    </form>
                </div><!-- .container -->
            </div><!-- .search-bar-mobile -->

        </div><!-- .container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="search-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://stage.federicalotti.com/">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Cerca:</span>
                    <input type="text" class="search-field" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cerca..." name="s" title="Cerca:">
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Cerca">
            </form>
        </div><!-- .container -->
    </div><!-- .search-bar -->

</div><!-- .nav-wrap -->
```

Sass code:

```
/*
 * nav
 */

.nav-wrap {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 5;
    box-shadow: 0 0 145px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);

    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateX(-30deg);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: 0.2s;

    &.open {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(0);
    }
}

.main-menu {
    text-align: center;

    > ul > li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 80px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        position: relative;

        > a:link,
        > a:visited {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 13px;
            letter-spacing: 1.2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000;
            transition: 0.1s;
        }
        > a:hover {
            color: $verde;
        }

        &.no-link {
            > a:hover {
                cursor: default;
            }
        }

        > .sub-menu {
            position: absolute;
            background: transparent;
            width: 320px;
            padding: 2px 0;
            top: 80px;
            left: -10px;
            display: none;

            > li {
                list-style: none;
                display: block;
                padding: 2px 0;
                line-height: normal;

                > a:link,
                > a:visited {
                    display: block;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100%;
                    background: #FFF;
                    color: #000;
                    letter-spacing: 1.2px;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    padding: 22px 30px;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    text-align: left;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    box-shadow: 0 5px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
                    opacity: 0;
                    transform: translateY(30px);
                }
                > a:hover {
                    color: $verde;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

jQuery code (I'm using [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/)):

```
qode = {

    window:         $(window),
    html:           $('html'),
    body:           $('body'),
    nav:            $('#nav'),
    burgerWrap:     $('.burger-wrap'),
    searchBar:      $('.search-bar'),
    header:         $('#header'),
    wrapper:        $('#wrapper')

};

/*
 * Mouse enter animation
 */

qode.body.on('mouseenter', '.main-menu > ul > li', function(){

    if ( qode.wrapper.width() > 1024 ) {

        var self        = $(this),
            subMenu     = self.find('> .sub-menu'),
            elements    = self.find('> .sub-menu > li a');

        subMenu.stop().fadeToggle(0);

        elements.stop().each(function(index){

            $(this).stop();

            $(this).velocity({
                opacity: [ 1, 0 ],
                translateY: [ 0, '30px' ]
            }, {
                delay: 75 * index,
                duration: 200
            });

        });

    } // if wrapper width

});

/*
 * Mouse leave animation
 */

qode.body.on('mouseleave', '.main-menu > ul > li', function(){

    if ( qode.wrapper.width() > 1024 ) {

        var self        = $(this),
            subMenu     = self.find('> .sub-menu'),
            elements    = self.find('> .sub-menu > li a');

        $( elements.get().reverse() ).stop().each(function(index){

            $(this).velocity({
                opacity: [ 0, 1 ],
                translateY: [ '30px', 0 ]
            }, {
                delay: 75 * index,
                duration: 200,
                complete: function(elems){
                    if ( elements.length === ( index + 1 ) ) {
                        subMenu.stop().fadeToggle(0);
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    } // if wrapper width

});
```

Comment: Can you modify the question to include a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the `z-index` on `.open`. I'm guessing in Safari it inherits in a different way?

```
&.open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0);
    z-index:6; // Make sure the z-index is higher as the one of the page content. 
}
```